# Adjust rowHeight attribute using grid from Material Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

On desktop, I want `rowHeight` equals to `80vh`. But I would like to change it dynamically to `100vh` when screen width is below 500px.

I don't know how to do it, here is the code.

**HTML**

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="80vh">
    <mat-grid-tile >
       ...
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

I don't want to do a workaround with CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in Angular without CSS when you use the `BreakpointObserver`, provided via Angular's Component Developer Kit (CDK).

What you need to do are the following steps.

1. Import LayoutModule in module
2. Import BreakpointObserver in component
3. Add dynamic value to HTML

### 1. Import LayoutModule in module

In your `app.module.ts`, import `LayoutModule` and add it to `imports` (it's part of Angular's CDK).

```js
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatGridListModule, LayoutModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

### 2. Import BreakpointObserver in component

Next to that, in your component with `mat-grid-list`, import CDK's `BreakpointObserver`. It's an observable that will check if it matches the condition.

```js
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

Then in your component's `ngOnInit()`, set the `rowHeight` of `mat-grid-list` to a default of `80vh` and let the observer do its job.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  rowHeight: string;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rowHeight = '80vh';
    this.detectBreakpoint();
  }

  private detectBreakpoint(): void {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe(['(max-width: 500px)']).subscribe(result => {
      this.rowHeight = result.matches ? '100vh' : '80vh';
    });
  }
}
```

If the viewport width matches the condition given (in this case `'(max-width: 500px)'`), set `rowHeight` to `100vh`, else keep it at `80vh`.

```js
this.breakpointObserver.observe(['(max-width: 500px)']).subscribe(result => {
  this.rowHeight = result.matches ? '100vh' : '80vh';
});
```

### 3. Add dynamic value to HTML

The last change is in your HTML, where you need to link the `rowHeight` from the component to your `rowHeight` attribute in `mat-grid-list`.

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" [rowHeight]="rowHeight">
```

### StackBlitz

See [this StackBlitz for an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjm53w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). `background-color` and `height` change when condition matches. You can see the GIF below for the effect.

Don't forget to 'unsubscribe' to the `Observable` when the component gets destroyed to prevent memory leaks.

[image: Animated image of BreakpointObserver behaviour]